# Hashmap в Java подробно

Tags: java

Пытаюсь разобраться с устройством Hashmap, как он работает под капотом)
Расскажу вам что я узнал и если что то не так пожалуйста поправьте меня)
И также есть пара вещей которые мне не понятны в Hashmap. В ходе объяснения я буду задавать вопросы, если вас не затруднит, пожалуйста ответьте)
Итак, в самом начале мы преобразуем ключ в хэш значение используя хэш функцию потом мы вычисляем индекс потому что значение хэш числа может быть огромным и получим OutOfMemory и вот тут вопрос как связан индекс и бакеты? Не совсем понимаю какую роль он выполняет. Также знаю что в бакете реализован односвязный список, знаю о hashcode и equals об их одновременном переопределении чтобы не допустить коллизию, также знаю о том что если что если ключи совпадают то старое значение перезаписывается новым. Почему время поиска значения O(1)? Храним ли мы бакеты в обычном массиве размером 16 ячеек?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основе хэшфункции вычисляется номер корзины(бакета) куда мы кладём наши ключ-значения. В этой хэшфункции происходит побитовый сдвиг и остаток от деления на 16, благодаря которому мы из хэшкода получаем номер для корзины (от 0 до 15), когда происходит заполнение на 0,75% нашего массива (это 12 элементов на 16 корзин), происходит увеличение массива в 2 раза(и так до 64, а дальше в красно-чёрное дерево перерождается) и опять идёт перерасчёт хэш значения(hash) и наши элементы(Node) перераспределяются по массиву из уже 32 ячеек.

Почему время поиска значения O(1)?
Потому что у нас в хэшмапе массив, а поиск в массиве по индексу происходит за константное время(ибо массив это один большой объект в памяти),но когда хэшмапа переродится в кч дерево, поиск будет уже логарифмический. При коллизии поиск будет происходить по хэшкоду, а после уже по значению, скорость мы потеряем до линейной

Можно ещё много говорить про хэшмапу. но её вы знать должны, частый вопрос на собесах)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а почему сложность О(1)? Ведь чтобы вернуть значение по ключу, сначала нужно определить бакет - это О(1), а потом пройтись по linkedList - это уже будет О(n), и по правилу О(1+n) = O(n). Я только начал алгоритмы и структуры данных, и пока плаваю в этой теме. Буду очень благодарен за объяснение

Comment: А можно уточнить?) Каждый бакет это массив? Или все бакеты разом образуют один массив?

Comment: нет, каждый бакет - это связный список, который хранится в ячейке массива. А все бакеты - это один массив. То есть эта структура представляет собой массив, в каждой ячейке которого лежит LinkedList

Comment: @had0uken
попробую написать по другому
Сперва 
1) поиск без коллизий О(1) лучшее ситуация для нас 
2) поиск с коллизиями О(n) худшая ситуация для нас
3) поиск в красно черном дереве О(log2(n)) хэшмапа пытается спасти ситуацию и перерождается в красно черное дерево, чтобы поиск был логарифмическим

Comment: не понятно. Это вы поиск по hashmap описываете или по бакету hashmap?

Comment: @had0uken не очень поняла, поиск по хэшмапе это и есть поиск по массиву(бакетам) и по связанному листу(списку нод), если не права поправьте)

Comment: Ну да, сначал ищется нужный бакет. Это происходит со сложность О(1). После нахождения нужного бакета начинается проход по LinkedList и это уже сложность О(n). То есть сумарная сложность поиска в хэшмапе тоже О(n)?

Comment: @had0uken, да если все значения попали в один бакет. Это статистически маловероятно, но, если известна хеш функция, злоумышленник может так подобрать ключи чтобы все они оказались в одном списке. Это приведёт к падению производительности. При анализе такой сценарий игнорируется, принимается что средняя длина списков в бакетах не велика и её можно считать за константу.

Comment: Так я не говорил ничего, что все попадет в 1 бакет. Допустим у меня массив из 16 бакетов. В 1ом-4 значения, во втором - 6 значений, в третьем - 1 одно значение и т.д. При запросе элемента из второго бакета - я сначала попаду во второй бакет со сложностью О(1), а потом буду проходится по всему LinkedList из 6 элементов, пока не найду свой ключ. (Если искомый элемент на последний в том листе). И это сложность О(n)?

Comment: @had0uken, да в вашем примере будет линейная сложность, но это в худшем случае, обычно поиск у вас будет за амортизированную O(1)

Comment: Так почему? О(1) будет только в случае, если искомый элемент будет идти первым в бакете. Ну так это маловероятно. При наличии, допустим, 10 элементов в бакете, шансы на то, что он будет 1ым в бакете 10%

Comment: В бакете же LinkedList и там чтобы найти нужный ключ, в любом случае придется пробегаться по ключам, пока не достигнут будет искомый

Comment: @had0uken, "маловероятно"  ключевое слово в вашем комментарии, какова вероятность, что 12 элементов попадут в массив размером 16 в одну и ту же ячейку  8 раз? (ибо после 8 перерождается в кч дерево). Вероятность конечно есть, если неправильно переопределён хэшкод.

Comment: А.. в момент когда я добавляю 9ый элемент в хэшмэп, то структура преобразуется в дерево? Этого не знал, тогда это все объясняет и расставляет на свои места. Спасибо вам!!

Comment: @had0uken, боюсь я вас обманула, в дерево перерождается если в бакете > 8 и в мапе > 64 одновременно. А так при неправильном переопределённом хэшкоде  хэшмапа выродится в список.

Comment: то есть в любом случае бакет не вырастет больше 8 элементов и это О(1). Понял, благодарю

Comment: @василина семенова. если в  результате коллизий в корзине будет 8 и более элементов, то произойдет перестройка в дерево (O log(n)). Но вот чтоб одновременно  было 64 корзины и в корзине 8 и более элементов и Map - начала перестраиватся в красно-черное дерево - этого я не видел. Может покажете в исходниках, где происходит такое вычисление с такой проверкой

Comment: @skyho, TREEIFY_THRESHOLD -> when a single bucket reaches this (and the total number exceeds MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY), it is transformed into a perfectly balanced red/black tree node.

Comment: The smallest table capacity for which bins may be treeified.
     * (Otherwise the table is resized if too many nodes in a bin.)
     * Should be at least 4 * TREEIFY_THRESHOLD to avoid conflicts
     * between resizing and treeification thresholds.
     */
    static final int MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64;

Comment: /**
     * The bin count threshold for using a tree rather than list for a
     * bin.  Bins are converted to trees when adding an element to a
     * bin with at least this many nodes. The value must be greater
     * than 2 and should be at least 8 to mesh with assumptions in
     * tree removal about conversion back to plain bins upon
     * shrinkage.
     */
    static final int TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8; -

Comment: Ну вот это работает отдельно, то есть если коллизии приведут к тому, что в ячейке будет более 8 элементов, то произойдет перестройка в дерево. То есть не будут ждать. пока общее количество корзин будет более 64

Comment: static final int MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64; (JDK 17) И исходя из описания java doc (то что вы написали,я у себя в java doc не нашел) - Исходя из этого и из : if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) < MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY) resize(); - в этом случае произойдет перераспределение элементов, то есть увеличится число корзин, то есть емкость HashMap. Если же корзин будет становиться больше чем пороговое значение, тогда количество корзин не будет увеличиваться, а будет в каждой корзине происходить перестройка из односвязанного списка в красно-черное дерево. Если я правильно понял, поправьте если не так.

Comment: кроме того, в документации говорится что :  static final int MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY = 64; - Наименьшая емкость таблицы, для которой бины(компоненты в корзине) могут быть древовидными. (В противном случае размер таблицы будет изменен, если в корзине слишком много узлов.)

Comment: Should be at least 4 * TREEIFY_THRESHOLD to avoid conflicts
     * between resizing and treeification thresholds - а вот это не понятно.